# Creating filtered and simplified data from deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have somewhat complex set of data that I would need to simplify and split into two different sets, based on a comparison on nested object property value.

Here's the data structure I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    object: { id: 123 },
    group: [
      {
        events: [
          {
            type: 'type',
            schedule: [
              {
                time: '2019-10-30T09:30:00+00:00',
              },
              {
                time: '2019-10-21T21:00:00+00:00',
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            type: 'type',
            schedule: [
              {
                time: '2019-10-24T09:30:00+00:00',
              },
              {
                time: '2019-09-22T21:00:00+00:00',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Most important thing would be to split this data into two different sets (arrays of objects), based on whatever or not the `schedule` value of `time` is in the past or in the future. It would also help to simplify the structure as a whole. There is a lot of properties attached to the objects and I'm fine brining in the whole object instead of just cherry-picking the important ones, as long as the nesting is logical and usable.

So something like this for the "past" data would be ideal:

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    events: [
      {
        type: 'type',
        schedule: [
          {
            time: '2019-10-21T21:00:00+00:00',
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'type',
        schedule: [
          {
            time: '2019-09-22T21:00:00+00:00',
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've been trying to use the different array methods (`filter` and `map`) to spit out something suitable for my needs, but can't figure out how to do it right. Mostly how to filter based on a nested value and copy over all the nesting structure on a match.

Comment: does your array contain multiple objects, and in turn does each of these objects have an id and a list of events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to restructure your array, [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to iterate over object properties in-place, and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the data based on a condition.

Using the code below, you can get an array of all past events. You can modify the condition accordingly to get all future events.

```
// mapping from old data array
const pastData = data.map(({object, group}) => ({ 
  // get all properties of the nested "object"
  ...object,

  // map "events" into a new structure
  events: group[0].events.map((event) => (
    {
      // get all other properties
      ...event,

      // include only those "schedule" objects where time is less than current date
      schedule: event.schedule.filter(schedule => new Date(schedule.time) < new Date()),
    }
  )),
}));
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    object: { id: 123 },
    group: [
      {
        events: [
          {
            type: 'type',
            schedule: [
              {
                time: '2019-10-30T09:30:00+00:00',
              },
              {
                time: '2020-10-21T21:00:00+00:00',
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            type: 'type',
            schedule: [
              {
                time: '2019-10-24T09:30:00+00:00',
              },
              {
                time: '2020-09-22T21:00:00+00:00',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const pastData = data.map(({object, group}) => ({ 
  ...object,
  events: group[0].events.map((event) => (
    {
      ...event,
      schedule: event.schedule.filter(schedule => new Date(schedule.time) < new Date()),
    }
  )),
}));

const futureData = data.map(({object, group}) => ({ 
  ...object, 
  events: group[0].events.map((event) => (
    {
      ...event,
      schedule: event.schedule.filter(schedule => new Date(schedule.time) >= new Date())
    }
  ))
}));

console.log('past data:', pastData, ', future data:', futureData);
```

Comment: This works great does exactly what I want. Learned a thing or two about array methods too. Thanks for providing an example against the mock data too!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `map` method and `spread` operator:

```
const result = data.map(({object, group}) => 
    ({ ...object, events: group.map(g=> g.events)}));
```

```js
const data =
  [
    {
      object: { id: 123 },
      group: [
        {
          events: [
            {
              type: 'type',
              schedule: [
                {
                  time: '2019-10-30T09:30:00+00:00',
                },
                {
                  time: '2019-10-21T21:00:00+00:00',
                }
              ],
            },
            {
              type: 'type',
              schedule: [
                {
                  time: '2019-10-24T09:30:00+00:00',
                },
                {
                  time: '2019-09-22T21:00:00+00:00',
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];



const result = data.map(({object, group}) => ({ ...object, events: group.map(g=> g.events)}));
console.log(result)
```